# How to call in JSP a Date

Tags: java, date, format, struts2

Before everything, I searched everywhere and even founds any things, but did not work.

**So, my question is:**

I have

1. `inicio.jsp`:

```
    <td><s:textfield name="dataInicio" id="redimensiona_inputs" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td><s:textfield name="dataFim" id="redimensiona_inputs" type="text" />
    </td>
```

2. `RelatorioServiceFacadeImpl.java`:

```
    public String gerarRelatorioTipoFuncional() {   
    List<RelAplicacaoTipoFuncionalVO> listRelatorio = relatorioServiceFacade.relTipoFuncional(aplicacao, gestor, dataInicio, dataFim);

        if (null == listRelatorio || listRelatorio.isEmpty()) {
            addActionError(getText("msg.erro.campo.obrigatorio",  new String[] { "existem campos vazios" }));
        }
        
        return SUCCESS; 
    }
```

3. `RelatorioAction.java`:

```
    private boolean validaCampos(String aplicacao, String gestor, Date dataInicio, Date dataFim) {
        
        if (gestor.isEmpty() || gestor == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (dataInicio.equals(null)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (dataFim.equals(null)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (dataInicio.after(dataFim)){
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Be returning this: `Invalid date format`.

Comment: This Stack Overflow is an English language only site. For Spanish, use https://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: The troublesome `Date` class is now replaced by the `Instant` class. The old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. I cannot see how that code would result in an invalid formatting error. Please delete extraneous code, write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting; most every basic date-time question has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to format the date: [Formatting Dates and Numbers](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html). The action context's locale is used when the date is formatted.

> An appropriate en_US format definition extension could look like this:
>
> ```
> format.date = {0,date,MM/dd/yy}
> ```

```
<s:textfield key="dueDate" value="%{getFormatted('format.date','dueDate')}" />
```